# SQL query with GROUP BY and conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a "stock market" data table with `contract` values. I want to get the volume (number of trades executed per day), and the close price, with the close price being the last recorded contract price that trading day.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contracts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1502 ;
```

I'm able to get the data I want (mostly!) by doing a query like this:

```
SELECT count(id) as volume, price, DATE(created_at) FROM `contracts` 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

However, I want the close price-- the price returned is the price of whatever record happens to be last by ID. Is there a way to get the last `price` value set by the `created_at` column?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One solution is to use a sub-query to  get that price

```
SELECT count(ctr.id) as volume, 
    (SELECT cc.price
        FROM contracts as cc 
        WHERE DATE(cc.created_at) = DATE(ctr.created_at)
        ORDER BY cc.created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1) as price, 
    DATE(ctr.created_at) 
FROM `contracts` as ctr
GROUP BY DATE(ctr.created_at)
```

**EDIT:** Changed the query to use `LIMIT` and select the price. I used `ODER BY DESC` because it will get the row with the latest date.

Comment: @user2989408-- will a subquery have a large performance hit? Or will this be minimal?

Comment: And work's this? I don't think that it do, what you want

Comment: this query fails with error "subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: thanks-- but now it's returning the same price for every date.

Comment: @user101289 Can you please check now, just added table aliases to the columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
   count(id) AS volume,
   DATE(created_at),
   (SELECT price
      FROM `contracts` as innerContracts
      WHERE innerContracts.id = outerContracts.id
      ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM `contracts` AS outerContracts
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Comment: testing this, it appears to return the same price for every row.

Comment: Updated my query, I was mistaken my first time around. This *should* work for you, hard for me to test when I don't have the database in front of me.

Comment: sorry, but now it's returning: `#1054 - Unknown column 'outerContracts.id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Try that one. If that doesn't work, could you show me the results of it? From what I can tell the syntax is correct and the logic should be working.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it Mike. That is working now, but the close price is not correct. Are you assuming in this query that the id / date fields correlate? They will in the "real" table but in my sample data they are a little mixed up.

Comment: What it should be doing is to grab the id, volume, and date from the table. Then create another tuple with the id, and closing price from the table. It should then join these on the id, creating a tuple with id, volume, date, closing price. Grouping by dates. What happens if you execute without the group by?

Answer (score 0):

There's several other answers already, but this is how I would return the specified resultset, using the specification that the "largest" id value for a given day is the id of the "last" contract.

```
SELECT d.volume
     , p.price     AS close_price
     , d.created_dt
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(c.id)          AS id
              , COUNT(c.id)        AS volume
              , DATE(c.created_at) AS created_dt
           FROM contracts c
          GROUP BY DATE(c.created_at)
       ) d
  JOIN contracts p
    ON p.id = d.id
```

Most of the work is done by the inline view (aliased as **`d`**), which is similar to the original query; this returns a single row for each date, along with a count of rows (`volume`) and the "largest" id value for the date (`id`).

Given that `id` is the primary key on the table, we can use that in a JOIN operation to retrieve the row from the contracts table (aliased as **`p`**), so we can retrieve the `price` column.

---

Another alternative would be use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
SELECT d.volume
     , ( SELECT p.price
           FROM contracts p
          WHERE p.created_at >= d.created_dt
            AND p.created_at < d.created_dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS close_price
     , d.created_dt
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(c.id)        AS volume
              , DATE(c.created_at) AS created_dt
           FROM contracts c
          GROUP BY DATE(c.created_at)
       ) d
```

In this example, I used the `created_at` column to determine the "last" contract for a given date. (We get the last one by ordering in descending order, and then using the LIMIT clause to ensure we return no more than one row.  The ORDER BY clause could just as easily reference `p.id` rather than p.created_at.)

Answer (score -2):

It isn't possible by this way
In other DBMS you have to have all collumns witch you select in GROUP BY clausule

Try this

```
SELECT volume, price, created_at FROM contracts JOIN ((
    SELECT count(id) as volume, Max(id) maxid FROM `contracts` 
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at)) AS s) ON (s.maxid = contracts.id)
```